# Can't create filtered replication rule through Harbor API

Tags: rest, harbor

I'm using the Swagger API tool built into harbor.  I've successfully created replication rules using the API, but the problem comes when I try to add a filter.  From trial and error, I've managed to work out that "type" can be something like name or tag. But when I try and add anything into value I get ""BAD_REQUEST", "message": "the type of filter value isn't string".

It seems to indicate that value needs to be set as "value": "hello-world", but that won't even execute.  "value" needs to be an object containing a key value pair it seems (that's the only way it will even execute), but whatever is placed in there, it complains it's not a string.  I've scoured for examples and I can't find any. How do I have to format the value parameter to get this working?

```
  "filters": [
{
  "decoration": "matches",
  "type": "name",
  "value": {"name": "hello-world"}
}
```

],

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, it's actually an error in the UI.  I imported the same json I was trying to use in swagger, and invoked it using the harborapi python library, and it worked fine.

Swagger just won't let you invoke the correct syntax